# Android Studio ignoring imported .jar library class variables

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm playing around with an Android app from a vendor that our company might be doing business with (so for legal reasons I'll leave out any names).  They sent me the source including a compiled .jar library that exposes Android's hidden classes (like android.os.SystemProperties) as well as enables hardware-specific functionality.

I imported their project and the library following this process [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library), but when trying to build I get,

`"error:  cannot find symbol method Foo() in class Bar"`

for several methods used throughout the code.  I inspected the library and found that these methods do indeed exist, so if the library imported successfully (which I assume because there are no errors concerning the hidden classes), why won't it find those variables?

I believe this is an issue of Android Studio looking up the class name "Bar", finding it in the SDK, and stopping there without checking the library .jar because when I right-click on the class in question, and select "Go To Declaration," it takes me to the SDK class, not the library class.  Any help is appreciated!

(Potentially) useful info:

- Android Studio v1.4
- JRE 1.8.0_60-b27 amd64
- Gradle v2.2.1 (jcenter repo)
- Android Plugin Version: 1.3.0
- Compile SDK: API 19: Android 4.4 (KitKat)
- Build Tools Version: 23.0.1

EDIT:

I guess I should clarify:  The .jar library I have has structure like

```
+--  library.jar
|    +-- android
|    |    +-- app
|    |    +-- content
|    |    +-- graphics
|    |    |    +-- PixelFormat
...
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

From Android Studio 1.3 prefered way of adding jar/aar libraries is by doing

File -> New -> Module -> Import Jar/Aar Package -> Select your jar, edit name and import

Then File -> Project Structure (Ctr+Alt+Shift+S(win) or CMD+; (mac))

Under your module on cart Dependencies adding module dependency by clicking + -> module dependency -> Imported Module Name Here

Comment: Hi Inverce,

Thank you for your response, but unfortunately that didn't seem to do the trick :/  The same methods and variables are not found.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: only suggetion is to check whatever you have proguard (build.gradle : minifyEnabled) turned on and disable it for now, as well as check whatever your jar actually has class files (via any jar lookoup tool :)